# Running multiple socket.io-client on multiple IPs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My goal is to run multiple instances of a socket.io-client with a different IP address each. To clarify: I don't want to control the IP address for each request, but for each socket.io connection. The IP addresses can be bound to the machine or used as proxies.

I want to do this to have a socket.io client connect to a game, but with a different IP address for every account.

I'm using the socket.io-client node module and couldn't find any documentation on how to connect through a proxy. I only found the socket.io-proxy module which is outdated.

Is there a way to make socket.io-client use proxies?

Another approach I thought of, is to use a virtual instance like GCE with multiple IP addresses bound to, and start multiple node apps which use the different IPs (is that even possible?).

How can I make any of that work, or do you have another idea?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Do you want to have a nodejs program running on a  machine with multiple IP addresses, and initiate outbound socket.io requests from that box while controlling which IP address each request uses? Please tell us a bit about *why* you want to do that so we can best help you.

Comment: Added a bit of explanation.